# Format cells that begin with an even number before a delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of tags that begin with a number:

eg.

```
  |    A     |
  -----------
1 |   1-text |
2 |  21-text |
```

How can I identify tags that begin with an even number so that I can format the cells? I mean an even number; ie. all of the digits before the delimiter.

Comment: "begin with an even number" - do you mean an even *digit* (eg "21-text") or even *number* (eg "12-text") ?

Comment: I mean an even number; ie. all of the digits before the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ISEVEN():

You can use [`ISEVEN()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iseven-function-aa15929a-d77b-4fbb-92f4-2f479af55356) to check if the given substring before the dash is an even number:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(LEFT(A1, FIND("-", A1) - 1)), "EVEN", "ODD")
```

#### ISODD():

You can also use the inverse of [`ISODD()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/isodd-function-1208a56d-4f10-4f44-a5fc-648cafd6c07a) to determine an even number:

```
=IF(ISODD(LEFT(A1, FIND("-", A1) - 1)) = FALSE, "EVEN", "ODD")
```

#### MOD():

You can also pass the numerical substring to [`MOD()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mod-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3) to determine if the modulus result of the value and `2` is equivalent to `0`:

```
=IF(MOD(LEFT(A1, FIND("-", A1) - 1), 2) = 0, "EVEN", "ODD")
```

Answer (score 1):

If, for example, `Cell A1` contained your text and you want to identify whether the first digit is even or odd you could use this formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,1)/2=INT(LEFT(A1,1)/2)
```

This will return `TRUE` for cells that start with an even number, `FALSE` for odd.

Alternatively, Excel has a built-in function called [**`ISEVEN`**](https://support.office.com/article/iseven-function-aa15929a-d77b-4fbb-92f4-2f479af55356). (Not to be confused with the [`EVEN`](https://support.office.com/article/even-function-197b5f06-c795-4c1e-8696-3c3b8a646cf9) function.

If you want to determine whether the entire number is even or odd (not just the first digit), you could search for the dash, something like:

```
=ISEVEN(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1))
```

...will return `TRUE` if the entire number is EVEN, `FALSE` for ODD.

---

### More Information:

- Office Support : [**ISEVEN Function**](https://support.office.com/article/iseven-function-aa15929a-d77b-4fbb-92f4-2f479af55356)
- Office Support : [**EVEN Function**](https://support.office.com/article/even-function-197b5f06-c795-4c1e-8696-3c3b8a646cf9)
- ExcelJet : [**Highlight Every Other Row**](https://exceljet.net/formula/highlight-every-other-row)